# Disable auto number duplicate file names upon save dialog

Tags: 18.04, files, duplicate-files

I am processing a lot of images one by one and when I attempt to save a file to my file system from any application, such as an image editor or even my web browser, if the initial folder that opens from the save dialog has a file with the same name, the file I am attempting to save is automatically changed by appending a space and a number within parenthesis.

`file.jpg` becomes `file (1).jpg` in the save dialog rather than retaining it's original name.

Can I disable this?

It is very time consuming to have to re-type and edit the file name for every single image before I save when my intention is to save over the original.

I know I can also find the identical file name in said folder and click it to reset the "save as" file name back to it's original so I will be prompted to overwrite but this too is cumbersome especially if there are a lot of images in the folder.

It would be nice to disable this auto number duplicate file names feature.

For anyone that says this is a duplicate...it probably is but...

When typing this question I was given some "similar suggestions" of which the first suggestion sounded very much like my question and the rest didn't, but mid-read of it's excerpt and before selecting it to read further, it disappeared from the list (not sure why) and now I can't seem to find it no matter how I re-word my question and search so here goes...this is probably a duplicate that I just can't find, sorry.

Comment: "I am processing a lot of images one by one" using which application? I use Gwenview and when I save an altered image, the original version is overwritten.

Comment: No locally installed app, just the browser using gravit.io.  My process is open local file in gravit.io, resize then save over original (have to remove the appended (1) after the file name, then upload to tinypng.com and same thing, save over original and have to remove (1) again from file name.

Comment: Add these specifics to the question. The normal behaviour when saving a file over an existing file is a confirmation dialog, not an automatic numbering. Indeed, the latter is what browsers do when you download files.

Comment: @vanadium When I save "file.jpg" from the browser, the save file dialog only appends the " (1)" to the end of the file name if a file with the same name already exists in the last opened folder.  In this scenario, if I want to overwrite the file, I cannot simply press save/carriage return twice so as to accept the overwrite, I must first find the original and click it so as to correct the "save-as" file name or I must manually edit the file name of the file being saved so as to remove the " (1)".  I understand this is behavior most prefer, for my scenario it adds steps to my workload.

Comment: Appears this might be an Application level feature request. OSX however has a solution, at least for some apps, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460217/finder-disable-appending-of-1-when-saving-same-file-name-ie-no-versionin